# How do I create multi level row level security in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, row-level-security

I am trying to use the automated row level security in tableau 8.1 but if I create the security at the highest level it doesn't pass the security to the children of the level.  I can only achieve this by creating a massive excel sheet that has every object that I want to allow access to.  I could use the manual way but that is too tedious.  I am sure someone has found a way around this but I can't find anything online.

Comment: Would it be possible to show some sample data so we can see the structure and thus determine the extent of the issue? :)

Answer (score 1):

Click the sheet on which you want to create the row level filter and then click on "Server" ---> "Create User Filter" . This will give you a list of all the columns available in that sheet  and then you can select the column which decides the row level security , something like Region_Code (or similar field if you have have) . There itself you can give the list of groups and users which can access with that filter so next time when only those users will access that sheet they will see the filtered data based on the column selected above however rest all the people can still see everything as no security /filter been applied to them.

This link has more details -  http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/row-level-security-and-user-filters